# My Stack Overflow question is in a strange state

Tags: support, questions

The following question of mine is in a strange state. Obviously some edits have been suggested. But when I open the question I see the two variants and that's all. I have a Reject button only which I cannot use. What should I do?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25133594

Comment: This is a link to the *suggested edit* on your question. The link to your *question* is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813083/how-to-change-orientation-of-custom-view-layout-by-code.

Comment: This is an indication of a UX problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you shared is to suggested edit review. If you navigate to the question itself (by clicking on its  - [How to change orientation of custom view layout by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813083/how-to-change-orientation-of-custom-view-layout-by-code)), you'll see a single revision (which by now included the suggested edit).